# What is the meaning of $\sqrt{\mathrm{var}(X)\mathrm{var}(P)-[\mathrm{cov}(X,P)]^2}$?

Tags: probability, variance, covariance, covariance-matrix, determinant

What is the meaning of the quantity:

$$\varepsilon=\sqrt{\mathrm{var}(X)\mathrm{var}(P)-[\mathrm{cov}(X,P)]^2}$$

Is there, for example, a geometric explanation? Is there a term for it in statistics?

Comment: if the answer ok for you @apadana, can you please accept and/or upvote it?

Answer (score 8):

It is the square root of the *determinant* of the covariance matrix (between $X$ and $P$). The determinant of the covariance matrix is called as [*Generalized Variance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_variance), which quantifies the co-variability of multivariate random variables to a scalar. What you write is the square root of it, so I believe it won't be too odd to call it as *Generalized Deviation*.

**Edit:** After some research, I found that, in some contexts, it's referred as [Generalized Standard Deviation](https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/conference/download.cgi?db_name=NASM2009&paper_id=1171), or [Wilk's standard deviation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003491615003589).

Comment: Have you seen "generalized deviation" used anywhere, or did you come up with that term?

Comment: @Dave I've come up with it actually.

Comment: "Co-variability" is more accurate, than "variability". E.g. if the determinant of a covariance matrix is zero, there's linear dependence among the de-meaned random variables. (In the two by two case here, $\epsilon = 0$ if and only if $X$ lies in the linear span of $P$ and $1$.)

Comment: Right @Michael changed it